# Wheel view in phonegap windows app

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I have an `android` application which contains a `wheelview` to change its items and select any specific item. Now I'm creating the app in `phonegap` using html and css so I took `ul` and `li` as an alternate to `wheelview`.

I have a `ul` inside a child `div` which is inside a parent `div`. `li` elements are scrollable in the `ul` in child `div`. Is there any way by which I can get the `li` element which is currently inside the child `div` after scroll?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="innerDiv">
    <ul id="list">
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Aries</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Taurus</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Gemini</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Cancer</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont">Leo</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Virgo</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Libra</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Scorpio</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Ophiuchus</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Sagittarius</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Capricorn</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Aquarius</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="sunSigndiv" >
          <span class="sunSignFont" >Pisces</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally after scroll to the last element in the `ul`, how can I move to the first element just to give feel of the `wheelview`.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shilpasoni/g4tfLdv9/1/)

Comment: visit-https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-pickerview/tree/master